# Creating dynamically sized arrays in For...Next loops

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I have price data, with multiple, but a variable number of prices recorded for each day. On a separate sheet I have a column vector of all the separate days. I need, next to each day, a row vector of all the prices for just that day.

I think the best way to go about it is to, for each day, copy the prices and put them in an array which I would be able to paste-transpose in the other sheet. To do this I have created two loops, but I don't know how to store the prices for each day and populate this dynamically sized array for each day as I go through the loop. I think I have to redim the array each loop, but how do I populate each element of the array as I go through the loop?

Here's a copy of where I am at.

```
Sub GroupDayData()

    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim RowCount2 As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Day As Date
    Dim No1 As Worksheet
    Dim No2 As Worksheet
    Dim TradePrice() As Double

    No1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    No2 = Worksheets("Sheet4")

    RowCount = Application.CountA(No1.Range("A:A"))
    RowCount2 = Application.CountA(No2.Range("A:A"))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'First I want to set the particular day I am looking at
    For r = 1 To RowCount2 + 1
    Day = Range("A" & r)
        'I then want to look at all values on that day
        For j = 1 To RowCount + 1
            If No1.Range("A" & j) = Day Then
            'This is where I am stuck. I want the code to populate an array as it runs through
            'this second loop, which I will paste and transpose in Sheet4, and then do the whole
            'thing again for the next day, therefore the size of the array is not constant.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Following comments, I have edited the code, however I am still not getting any output appearing in Sheet 2 (No2). The matter seems to be effectively populating the array, and pasting it in the selected range.

```
Sub DayData()

    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim ClmnCount As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim No1 As Worksheet
    Dim No2 As Worksheet
    Dim Day As Date
    Dim Price() As Variant
    'Does this need to be declared as Double?
    Dim e As Integer

    Set No1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set No2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    RowCount = No1.Application.CountA(No1.Range("A:A")) + 1
    ClmnCount = No2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r = 1 To ClmnCount
        Day = No2.Cells(1, r)

        For j = 1 To RowCount
            If No1.Range("A" & j).Offset(1, 0) = Day Then
            'This loop will look through all date values and count the number that are the same
            e = e + 1
            'First I need to count how many elements are in the particular array
            ReDim Preserve Price(e)
            'Redim the array with its size
            'Is there a more efficient way rather than using redim each loop
            Price(e) = Range("B" & j).Offset(1, 0).Value
            'I think the problem is here
            End If
        Next j

        No2.Range(Cells(2, r), Cells(e + 1, r)) = Price
        Erase TradePrice

    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use a `Variant Variable` which will take all the range values in one go. To get the range you use *Range Filter Method*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possible approaches. Depending on the situation, I use option 1 or 2. I almost never use 3.

### 1. Count ahead of time

Loop once to count how many elements the array will need to contain. Them `Dim` the array accordingly. Then loop a second time to populate the array.

**Pros**: Don't have to guess array size. Get element count immediately, which you may need somewhere else anyway.

**Cons**: Looping twice = small performance hit. Slightly less readable.

### 2. Prepare for the worst

`Dim` the array so that it can accommodate the maximum conceivable number of elements (in your case this is presumably `(RowCount2 + 1) * (RowCount + 1)`). Then loop to populate it, keeping track of how many elements were written to it. Finally, trim it down to that exact number of elements using `Redim Preserve`.

**Pro**: Loop only once; best performance.

**Con**: Array too large to start with; only a problem if memory is an issue.

### 3. Make it up as you go along

Loop to populate array, resizing array with `Redim Preserve` each time you add an element to it.

**Pro**: Arguably the most readable.

**Con**: Repeatedly calling `Redim Preserve` can seriously slow things down as VBA repeatedly has to look for new RAM real estate. That's why I never do this.

Comment: I have taken on board your comments and amended some of the code as per your first method, but I am not getting any output. It may just be a simple error, but I am not sure how I need to change it.

Comment: Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)).

Comment: I've stepped through my code, and I'm getting all the correct values, except at the line No2.Range(Cells(2,r),Cells(e+2,r)).Value=Price I am getting the error, "Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Yes, and did you watch what the values of `e` and `r` were when this happened? That will give you your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can dynamically resize an array

```
Redim Preserve TradePrice(newSize)

TradePrice(LastElement) = theNewValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed Jean-Francois Corbett's first method and came up with the following solution to my question:

Option Explicit

Option Base 1

Sub DayData()

```
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim ClmnCount As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim No1 As Worksheet
Dim No2 As Worksheet
Dim Day As Date
Dim Price() As Double
'Difference between a variant as array and an array of variants
Dim e As Integer

Set No1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set No2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

RowCount = No1.Application.CountA(No1.Range("A:A"))
ClmnCount = No2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = 1 To ClmnCount
    Day = No2.Cells(1, r)
    e = 0

    For j = 1 To RowCount
        If No1.Range("A" & j).Offset(1, 0) = Day Then
        'This loop will look through all date values and count the number that are the same
        e = e + 1
        'First I need to count how many elements are in the particular array
        ReDim Preserve Price(e)
        'Redim the array with its size
        Price(e) = No1.Range("B" & j).Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next j

    e = e + 1
    No2.Range(Cells(2, r), Cells(e, r)).Value = Application.Transpose(TradePrice)
    'This is where I went wrong, first I needed to transpose my array, and second,
    'given I was starting from row 2, I need to add 1 to e, as well as include
    'Option Base 1

    Erase Price

Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

End Sub